# Running code in a different tmux pane

Tags: tmux

I am new to vim and tmux.

### TL;DR

I want to have tmux set up so that I have a pane for my (python) code and a pane for the output of the code.

### What I know

Now, from vim I can do a command like `:!python %` to run/interpret my code, but the problem is that it displays the results, on the same screen, instead of the code. I have to end the program to see the code again.

### What I found

I can do something like `tmux run-shell -t 2 "echo hello"` to send the output to a different pane, but this still replaces the code with `Press ENTER or type a command to continue`.

### What I'd like

I'd love to know how can I send the output of the code to a different pane without disturbing my code pane.

Comment: I think it should be possible to switch to the pane and run python file from there or am I missing anything?

Comment: @MaximKim Yeah that would work but I'd like to bee able to map that into F5 or something so I could compile the code without needing to switch pane and type the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating [vim-simpl](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-simpl) for this. One function allows you to create a REPL (mapped to `<leader>t` in my config, as below), and another to load a file (mapped to `<localleader>l` in my config). With some effort, I can add python support out-of-box.

---

If you have vim8, it's easy to set up a mapping to open a `:terminal`, to which you can then send commands (like build and run code).

My workflow is something like

1. Edit python code
2. Try some code in the python interpreter (`<Leader>t`)
3. Copy or write in the code
4. Either tmux split, `:term`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, or `:quit` to run my script (with sessions, I can then get a semblance of where I was with `vim -S`).

I have seen several answers on this site dedicated to opening a `:term` and sending commands to it. There are also tmux plugins for vim that might help you do this. My alternative (below) is to let the shell do its thing (run code), but provide a way to do that in vim. It also lets me play with interpreters in vim with a minimum of fuss.

At the end, I do provide a possibility of something more like "run code" then "run an interpreter." It is untested, however.

---

I have these mappings:

```
" Terms and interpreters
" set b:interpreter for filetypes to affect the term
nnoremap <Leader>t :call terminal#run('++close')<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>T :call terminal#run()<CR>
```

which use this code (I should just make this a plugin at this point):

```
" autoload/terminal.vim
" Functions for dealing with the terminal

" Global function for calling terminal with the appropriate interpreter
" b:interpreter controls the program run
function! terminal#run(...) abort
  let l:interpreter = get(b:, 'interpreter', &shell)
  let l:command = 'term'
  if a:0
    for l:opt in a:000
      let l:command .= printf(' %s', opt)
    endfor
  endif
  let l:command .= printf(' %s', l:interpreter)
  execute l:command
endfunction
```

Then, in `after/ftplugin/python.vim`, I have

```
let b:interpreter = 'python'
```

I have similar definitions for lisp (`clisp`), ruby (`irb`), and more.

You could probably even do something like `let b:interpreter = 'python '.expand('%')`, so that the "interpreter" is actually "run this file." Then you would prefer `<Leader>T`, which, in my mappings, does not close the terminal when it finishes.

---

I'm not hating on tmux. I actually use it anytime I'm in a terminal. But for running code, it can be nice to pop open an integrated terminal, particularly for interpreted languages.

---

If the program is not interactive, the Clam plugin is quite useful.

Comment: Thanks! This works out really well, It's nice that at the end it also gives all the prints as a vim file(looks like it's not exactly a file but a buffer or something I dunno, still nice).

Comment: Its a terminal buffer. While its executing you can get to “normal” mode too. Read :help :term @DanielCohenHillel

Answer (score 6):

The run-shell example you mention looks identical to that in
[my 'Unix & Linux' post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416453/run-build-command-from-vim-send-output-to-another-tmux-pane/416480#416480)
on this topic so you may have read that. If so, at the very end I mention use of a mapping to prevent external commands (e.g. a 'make' command or equivalent) from interrupting the vim session in too disruptive a way. Admittedly, it's just a small update to the answer with a basic example.

A more substantive example might be

```
nnoremap <leader>X :!tmux run-shell -b -t 3 'cd mybuilddir && make arg1 arg2... 2>&1'<CR><C-L>
```

Unlike the original this shows how to quote the shell command and use `2>&1` to ensure that errors sent to stderr appear in the same pane as regular output.

I also included run-shell flag `-b` which, as mentioned in the U&L answer, tells tmux to start the command in the background. If the shell command does anything wonky (like start by sleeping) this is an additional safeguard against interrupting the vim session. I'd try your own command with and without `-b` and use whatever works best.

Finally, if you have a complex shell (Bash) command you might want to do something like:

```
nnoremap <leader>X :!tmux run-shell -b -t 3 '{ cd mybuilddir; do this; do that; ... ; make arg1 arg2...; } 2>&1'<CR><C-L>
```

This, for one, avoids having to specify `2>&1` for each command. (Important: Bash requires that the braces be separated from the shell commands by whitespace and the last command, before `}`, be followed by `;`).

If you have further questions on this approach let me know.

Comment: Also, Dispatch (tpope) makes all of this fun and easy :P

Comment: Well not exactly...it doesn't run commands in existing panes or call `run-shell`. :P (It appears it always creates a new, dedicated pane with `new-window` or variant. Those commands accept a shell-command to be run on initialization.) Being serious, though, yes that's a good solution if you want something more than a quick and dirty approach.

Answer (score 4):

If you build tmux from Git master you can send the output to an empty pane, for example:

```
mybuildcommand|tmux splitw -dI -c/my/source/directory
```

I don't know how to stop vim hiding the code while this is running however.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Why does this need the `master` branch source compiled? Is this feature not present in the most recent release? In vim, the typical "unhide" sequence involves the mapping pressing `<CR>` for you, or doing some kind of `:redraw!`

Answer (score 2):

OK so I found a bit of a work around that works.
I first declare a new command that gets as an input a command and executes the given command and then redraws the screen

```
command! -nargs=1 Silent execute ':silent !'.<q-args> | execute ':redraw!'
```

And on the next line it uses that command to send the interpreter command to a different pane.

```
map <F6> :Silent tmux send-keys -t 2 C-z 'python %' Enter
```

Comment: You probably don't need the `!` on `command`, and you almost certainly want `nnoremap` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with [Vim-Slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime).

The plugin allows you to send selections of text (current line, highlighted entry, etc.) from Vim running in one tmux pane to another tmux pane. (It also supports GNU Screen.)

It doesn't try to do bi-directional communication, which could be seen as a negative, but it's extremely flexible and lets you send text from Vim to *anything* running in the other pane (bash, SQL, any language with a REPL, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on pdoherty926's suggestion of using [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime). I use the following functions in my vimrc combined with vim-slime to map the F7 key to send the current line to the python shell window, and F8 to send the current selection buffer (i.e. the previously yanked/copied lines)

```
nnoremap <F7> :call <SID>slime_runline()<CR>
nnoremap <F8> :call <SID>slime_runselection()<CR>

" send the line beneath the vim cursor to the tmux window
" bound to F7 key
function! s:slime_runline()
   if getline('.') =~ "^\s*$"
      call cursor(getpos('.')[1]+1, col('.'))
      return
   endif
   let cmd = "SlimeSend1 ".getline('.')
   if matchstr(cmd, ':') != ''
      let cmd = cmd."\n"
   endif
   exec cmd 
   call cursor(getpos('.')[1]+1, col('.'))
endfunction

" send yanked lines to the tmux window
" bound to F8 key
" note that the operation works on the vim selection buffer,
" regardless of whether or not yank was the last action
function! s:slime_runselection()
   if mode() =="v"
      return
   endif
   let start = getpos("'<")[1]
   let end = getpos("'>")[1]
   let cmd = start.",".end."SlimeSend"
   echo cmd 
   exec cmd 
endfunction
```

For simple configuration with tmux, i also include the following in my vimrc to send lines to the bottom tmux pane

```
let g:slime_default_config = {"socket_name": "default", "target_pane": "{bottom-left}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following mapping

```
" Save current file and rerun previous command in previous tmux window.
map <leader>t :up<CR>:execute 'silent !tmux select-window -t :{last} && tmux send-keys Up Enter'<CR>
```

This assumes that you are currently editing a script and that you have executed it already once in another tmux window. I detailed this approach [here](http://the-efficient-programmer.com/shell/faster-command-execution.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think a plugin usage will be better since you are not limiting yourself to plugin.

For now I think there are two plugins that is worth checking out

- [Vimux](https://github.com/benmills/vimux)
- [VTR](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-runner)

Or if you prefer to show the result in vim quickfix window, you can use the [Dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin instead

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use this plugin:
https://github.com/preservim/vimux

Then you set the following in the .vimrc.

```
Plugin 'preservim/vimux'
let g:VimuxOrientation = "h" 

let g:VimuxHeight = "50"

map <leader>rb :call VimuxRunCommand("clear; python3 " . bufname("%"))<CR>
```

And there you go, when you press `<leader>rb`, it simply runs and displays the code in the side window.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [Tbone](https://github.com/tpope/vim-tbone) plugin which can run arbitrary tmux commands. `:Twrite` sends text to a specified pane.